# Spring configuration xml file

Tags: java, spring

i'm configuring a project but spring configuration file gives error as shown in image:[image]

my spring configuration cxf.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
  http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
```

```
<jaxws:inInterceptors>
 <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor"/>
 <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
   <constructor-arg>
     <map>
       <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken"/>
       <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText"/>
       <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="com.nightingale.cxf.servlet.PWCallback"/>
     </map>
   </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
</jaxws:inInterceptors>
<jaxws:properties>
    <entry key="faultStackTraceEnabled" value="true"/>
</jaxws:properties>
```

Comment: paster your spring config xml file code

Comment: There seems to be a difference in the Spring Beans schema version. Your `cxf.xml` is using `spring-beans-2.0.xsd` and eclipse seems to be using `spring-beans-2.5.xsd`.

Comment: what changes should i make? In lib or in cxf.xml file

Comment: What version of spring are you using?

Comment: as i checked spring 2.5 in class path but i've download code from svn so why this file is there?

Comment: Well that is not something that I don't know. Try to change to 2.5 in your cxf.xml